# Append to a buffer using fread

Tags: c, pointers, fread

How do I append data to a buffer:

I have a buffer:

```
uint8_t* buff = malloc((uint8_t*)malloc(BLOCK+1);
```

Now I want to read into it using fread: (I assume length < BLOCK)

```
fread(buff, 1, length, file)
```

At the second `fread` I want to append data to the buffer
Will `fread(buff + length, 1, length, file)`  modify my starting pointer ?
Do I need to save the start pointer? What other options do I have ?

Comment: C is not C++, and C++ is not C. What language are you *really* programming in? Also please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: you mean `(uint8_t*)malloc(BLOCK + 1);` right?

Comment: you `malloc` the result of `malloc`? (if the parens would match ...)

Comment: What's the _starting pointer_ you mention? What are you _actually_  trying to achieve? Please read this: [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: Shouldn't it be : `uint8_t* buff = (uint8_t*)malloc(BLOCK+1);`? BTW: in C you write simply: `uint8_t* buff = malloc(BLOCK+1);` without the cast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first read might be:

```
size_t nbytes = fread(buff, 1, length, file);
```

Your second read might then be:

```
size_t xbytes = fread(buff + nbytes, 1, min(length, BLOCK + 1 - nbytes));
```

(where `min()` might be: `static inline size_t min(size_t x, size_t y) { return (x < y) ? x : y; }`, of course).

The starting offset is where the previous read left off; the length to read is either `length` again, or the space left over — whichever is smaller.

When you're done, the total number of bytes of data is `nbytes + xbytes`.  You should check for zeros, meaning that the reads failed.